# Eclipse RCP & Hibernate Entity Mapping - class not found

Tags: hibernate, mapping, eclipse-rcp

while starting my application I get a "classNotFound"-Exception. Maybe you can help me solve this problem:

Structure of my plugins:

1)my.hibernate    <--all necessary hibernate jars
2)my.persistance  <--entities and mapping, DB-connectors and so on, dependency to 1) activated
3)my.starter      <--startplugin with a view. Dependancy to 2) activated

I get a connection to the database, but when the entities are loaded (mapped by Annotations, not *.hbm.xml) I get the described exception. I should mention that the my.persistance plugin contains Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: my.hibernate, and my.hibernate contains Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered.

My opinion is that the the hibernate annotations jar does not know the my.persistance plugin, including the exported packages. Some sollutions?

Comment: I recommend using EclipseLink instead of Hibernate, especially when you are using standard-JPA. It already provides OSGi-Metadata so you dont need the Buddy-Policy.

Comment: oh, thank you for the hint, I'll have a look on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. The problem was not the wrong classpath setting or some wrong dependancies, it was just hibernate's command

```
<mapping package="some.long.package.destination">
<mapping class="EntityToBeMapped">
<mapping class="FurtherEntityToBeMapped">
```

I thought this is the short form of mapping

```
<mapping class="some.long.package.destination.EntityToBeMapped"/>
<mapping class="some.long.package.destination.FurtherEntityToBeMapped"/>
```

without having to type in the package declaration all the time. After removing the "mapping package"-command entity mapping with annotations worked as intended.